# Is there a way to combine two data while maintaining the Arrow format in R?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

###### Is there a way to combine 2 data read by an Arrow package! However, I would like to keep the arrow format intact. There may be a way to do it like below, but it takes too much time to frame the data and then apply the rbindlist function, hence my question.

```
install.packages("arrow")
library("arrow")

a <- arrow::open_dataset("a.parquet")
b <- arrow::open_dataset("b.parquet")
a1 <- as.data.frame(a)
b1 <- as.data.frame(b)
```

###### Spending too long time if the size of a, b is very big.

```
merge <- rbindlist(list(a1, b1))
```

###### Please new idea

I look forward to a quick way to combine both data in Arrow format, or even if you don't.

Comment: I'm a fan of `data.table` and use it daily, but for "lazy" operations that both `arrow` and `dplyr` support, for larger datasets one should likely stay with arrow/dplyr as long as possible before the eventual `%>% collect()` into R's memory. If @gowerc's answer does not work for you (i.e., schema are not the same), then I suspect your only path to doing this _lazily_ is to do identical `dplyr`-pipes on each (all) of the files, filtering/reducing the data size, then collecting individually before calling `rbindlist`.

Comment: Can you explain what type of operations you want to do on the data? Do you want to write it to a database or disk, do you want to run queries against it with arrow, or with another package?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your reply. I'll try to filter/reduce the data size before calling rbindlist :)

Comment: @amoeba I want to write it to a database and use only arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow package supports <strike>partitioning</strike> reading multiple parquet files at once which may achieve what you are after (see note below about partitioning from @r2evans).  That is assuming the datasets have an identical schema then you can open multiple files in a single call to `open_dataset` which will then be treated as if they were a single file e.g.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

file1 <- tempfile()
file2 <- tempfile()
write_parquet(iris, file1)
write_parquet(iris, file2)

files <- c(file1, file2)
x <- open_dataset(files)
x |>
    select(Sepal.Length) |>
    nrow()
```

Full details can be found in the [vignette](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html)

Comment: Note that while arrow does support partitioning, this code does not use partitioning. All this code demonstrates is the perfectly salient fact that `open_dataset`'s first argument is `sources=`, which is defined as *"a character vector of paths or URIs to individual data files"*. Your suggested code is correct (given your stated assumption), it's just for a different reason.

Comment: For partitioning to be a factor, I would expect file paths such as `./data/Species=setosa/1.pq` and `./data/Species=versicolor/1.pq`, with or without a `Species` column in the `pq`. Whether `Species` is present or not in the actual `pq` files, then `open_dataset("./data") %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% collect()` would do as one would hope: read from only one of the parquet files.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for the clarification, is there a proper term for what is happening then when you do provide multiple file paths or is it just that "open_dataset can read from multiple files at once" ?

Comment: No special term, just what you said (and what I cited from `?open_dataset`). There are (at least) three cases: (1) open single file; (2) open a "simple directory" with pq files, which opens all 1-nested parquet files within (same schema); and (3) open a directory with partitioning, either hive-style or not. In the first and second, nothing special, parquet columns are all that are seen; in the third, even if the partitioning variables (either hive or named via the `partitioning=` argument) are not in the parquet files themselves, they are included in the data and can be used for filtering.

Comment: (That's not to say that the OP might not benefit from partitioning, regardless of whether it currently exists. Different question entirely :-)

Comment: @gowerc: FWIW, when multiple Arrow datasets of the same schema are combined like in the above code snippet, we call this a UnionDatset, see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/dataset.html#classarrow_1_1dataset_1_1_union_dataset.

Comment: @gowerc Thank you for your kindly reply. However, the "write_parquet(iris, file1 or file2)" code takes too long to execute. Is there any other way?

Comment: @AAA - The `write_parquet()` code was only used here to setup example datasets based on the iris dataset (so that I had a fully reproducible example).  In your case as you already have existing parquet files then your first line of code should be the `open_dataset(c(<file1>, <file2>))`

Comment: @gowerc 
Is there a good way to combine them after reading them, other than putting them together before reading them!  

(Combine before reading)
`arrow::open_dataset(c("a.parquet", "b.parquet"))`  

(Combine after reading)  
`a <- arrow::open_dataset("a.parquet")  
b <- arrow::open_dataset("b.parquet")  
a1 <- a %>% filter(date == "2023-07-21")`  

I'd like to combine a1, b.

Comment: As far as I can tell no. I think your best bet in this scenario would be to change the name of the files to make use of partioning and then do some conditional filtering based upon the partion value  e.g.  `filter(partition == "A",  date = "2023-07-21")` or more generally filter upon some unique identifier within the first dataset.  Or alternative if you filter reduces the dataset to a small enough size just write the filtered part to its own dataset which you can combine with the second.